# Different order when using scalar or array assignment on the result of parameter expansion with the Oa flag

Tags: zsh, parameter-expansion

In zsh, if I do the following

```sh
x=(1 2 3)
y=${(Oa)x}
z=(${(Oa)x})
```

then `echo $y` will output `1 2 3` but `echo $z` will output `3 2 1`.

Obviously y is a scalar and z is an array but why does the scalar assignment to y not end up assigning "3 2 1" to it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that because the rules of substitution, the '10. *Force Joining*' is taken precedence over the '19. *Ordering*'.

Here is the zsh documentation:

> **Rules**
>   Here  is  a  summary  of  the rules for substitution...
>   ...
>   10. *Forced joining*
>   If  the  `(j)`  flag is present, or no `(j)` flag is present but the string is to be split as given by rule 11., and joining  did not take place at rule 5., any words in the value are joined together using the given string or the first character of $IFS  if none.  Note that the `(F)` flag implicitly supplies a string for joining in this manner.
>   ...
>   19. *Ordering*
>   If  the  result  is still an array and one of the `(o)` or `(O)` flags was present, the array is reordered.
>
> --- [`zshparam(1)`, rules, zsh parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Rules)

---

`y=${(Oa)x}` **vs** `z=(${(Oa)x})`

The first form is scalar assignment, and latter is to assign an array value.

> **Description**
>   ...
>   The value of a scalar parameter may also be assigned by writing:
>   `name=value`
>
> --- [`zshparam(1)`, description, zsh parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Description-3)

...

> To assign an array value, write one of:
>   `set -A name value ...`
>   `name=(value ...)`
>   `name=([key]=value ...)`
>
> --- [`zshparam(1)`, array parameters, zsh parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Parameters)

So, ther first form produces scalar value and latter array value:
(`echo` the value with [parameter expansion flag `(q)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) in a verbose form.)

```
x=(1 2 3)
y=${(Oa)x}
echo ${(qqq)y}  ;# look the `y` value in a verbose form with `(qqq)` 
#=> "1 2 3"     ;# forced joining and resulted scalar value
z=(${(Oa)x})
echo ${(qqq)z}
#=> "3" "2" "1" ;# resulted array value
```

> In scalar  assignment,  value is expanded as a single string, in which the elements of arrays are joined together
>
> --- [`zshparam(1)`, array parameters, zsh parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Parameters)

This is fit into the rule 10. if the form is not in double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't quite follow why this would happen for the scalar assignment but not the array one. Would you be able to expand a bit on why the forced joining would happen in the one case but not the other? Does it being a scalar assignment somehow set some flags differently implicitly?

Comment: From `man zshparam`, "In  scalar  assignment, value is expanded as a single string, in which **the elements of arrays
       are joined together**; [...]". I think this is implicitly part of Rule 5, though not stated as such. As far as rule 19 is concerned, the expansion of `x` is not an array anymore in the scalar assignment, but it is in the array assignment.

Comment: In other words, the context of the expansion determines whether `(Oa)` is ignored or not.

Comment: Thanks very much @chepner. I'm not sure that this is Rule 5. But I honestly (mis?)read as it coulde be Rule 10 because the form is not in double quotes.

Comment: It's not clear to me, either. My interpretation was that because the right-hand side of a scalar assignment behaves as though double-quoted, then by the time you reach Rule 10, the array elements *have* been already joined as if Rule 5 had done the joining. But either way, one of the two rules have joined the array elements into a single string by the time Rule 19 checks if there is an array value to which `(Oa)` can be applied.

Comment: @chepner I would like to know that it fits into Rule 5 or 10. So, I try to check the rule between 5 to 10. I've tested this, (Rule 7. Modifiers): `a=(aa ab ac); x=${a:s/a/}; echo ${(qqq)x} #=> "a b c"`. A modifier `:s` effects all the array elements. So, it seems that Rule 7 sees all the array elements. I would like to say (but I'm not sure though, again) it fits into Rule 10.

Comment: That seems like pretty good evidence that Rule 10 is the one doing the joining :)